# Change string resource by flavor / debug-build

Tags: android, build, resources

Let's say we have strings_test.xml, which stores string values for testing and should be shown in a debug-release. When the apk gets build as a release version all values should be change to an empty string e.g. `<string name="test_some_card_text">@string/empty</string>`.

Is there a possibility to achieve this?

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes you can do that inside your app gradle under buildTypes..

```
 buildTypes {
        mybuild {
                 resValue "string", "test_some_card_text", '"test"'
                 resValue "string", "other_text", '"other"'
                }
         debug {
                 resValue "string", "test_some_card_text", '"test"'
                 resValue "string", "other_text", '"other"'
              }
          }
```

Then access it like this.

```
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.test_some_card_text);
getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.other_text);
```

For build you need to select that `build variants` and have to build it.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in my strings.xml file as a Doctype entity?

Comment: @Syzygy Can you please elaborate your question or ask a new question?

Comment: Madhukar, I believe @Syzygy refers to what is partially answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51310147 However, I'm also having trouble using flavors to switch an XML entity (used for a String).

Comment: Can this be accessed in XML files as string resource?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Gradle lets you override strings.

- Add this inside buildTypes{} in your app/build.gradle

  debug {
                  applicationIdSuffix "debug"
              }
- That should create a directory titled `debug` next to `main`. If not then manually create one. (Seriously, I haven't tried this, but I know this is possible.)
- Then if your `strings_test.xml` is under `res/values`, create similar directory structure under debug/ and put your strings_text.xml with debug specific strings there. This will show up in your debug build. The ones under release/main/res/values will show up in your release build.

PS: You can override all res and asset data like this according to buildTypes and flavor. You can't **override** Java files though, you could however **add** them.

Answer (score 4):

As @Aditya Naik  said it is possible using Flavors. 
Official doc says

> BuildType -> Flavor -> main -> Dependencies.
>
> This means that if a resource is declared in both the Build Type and in main, the one from Build Type will be selected.
>
> Note that for the scope of the merging, resources of the same (type, name) but different qualifiers are handled separately.
>
> This means that if src/main/res has
>
> - res/layout/foo.xml
> - res/layout-land/foo.xml
>
>   and src/debug/res  has
> - res/layout/foo.xml 
>     Then the merged resource folder will contain the default foo.xml from src/debug/res but the landscape version from src/main/res

**for more info visit [Official doc - Resource Merging](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging)**

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change the string value after creation of the apk.
But you can assing the value to text or edittext ... etx dynamically after creation of the apk.

Comment: Yes, thats true.. But it seems to be a bit unhandy to override each TextView/EditText itself. There should be a possibility by providing different build flavors, I guess, but I didn't find a solution yet.

Comment: can you let me know why you want to change the string value so that i can give you some idea

Comment: When I test my apps I want to be able to insert some dummy data in the GUI (including multiple lines in various combinations, etc) -> let's call it stress-testing the layouts. :) But it would be nice if these test-resources are overridden in a release build.

Comment: yes but we cannot do it .create a table in the database with name and id and pass all the values to the db and from to gui .It is bit lengthy but only one time process.for one of my gui i did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

For those who come here looking for some way to apply a similar method to `raw` resources, I dealt with it using `buildConfigField`.

```
gradle
...
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...

        buildConfigField "int", "shared_resource_name", 'R.raw.debug_resource_name'

        ...
    }
    prod {
        ...

        buildConfigField "int", "shared_resource_name", 'R.raw.prod_resource_name'

        ...
    }
}
```

Pay attention to the quotes. After that, place `BuildConfig.shared_resource_name` in the files wherever `R.raw.resource_value` used to be accessed directly.

This can be used to other resources I think.